# Failed Input help, Int and Char, C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to determine if the user enters something other than a character, and specifically, that they only enter m or s. See code below.

Note:

`filingStatus` is a `char`

```
do
{

    cout << "Please enter your filing status (s for single, m for  married)" << '\n';
    cin >> filingStatus;

    if (cin.fail())
    {
        cin.clear();    
        dataTest = 1;
        cout << "Error, please enter a valid input!" << '\n';
        double dummyDouble;
        cin >> dummyDouble;
        if (cin.fail())
        {
            cin.clear();
            cin >> dummyString;
        }

    }
    else
    {

        if (filingStatus == 'm' || filingStatus == 's')
        {
            dataTest = 0;
        }

        else
        {
            cout << "Error, please enter either m or s!" << '\n';
            dataTest = 1;
        }

    }

} while (dataTest == 1);
```

Here is the problem, if I enter 1000 for example, the input doesn't fail. It instead stores the 1 in the char, and since 1 is neither m or S, it loops again, then it puts the 0, loops again, puts another 0, etc.

My understanding was it would fail when it sees  that a integer is being stored in a char, but obviously it isn't failing.

My question is:

1. Why isn't the input failing? How can I change it so if someone enters a string, or number that it fails?

Answer (score 2):

The input isn't failing, because `'1'` is a character. Digits are a subset of characters.

Read into a `std::string`. Then test whether that string consists of a single character from your desired range.

Note however, that reading into a string using `>>` stops at the first white space. To prevent this and read the whole line instead, read using [`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that `fillingStatus` is of `char` type.

Now even if you enter a numeral say '1' or '0', it is read as a char. Hence cin does not fail. It just keeps on looping as per your code.

Also, while reading an invalid char, you should be careful of clearing the input buffer because the return character '\n' stays along with other characters in the input buffer.

I would do it something like the following:

```
while ( !(cin >> fillingStatus) || (filingStatus != 'm' && filingStatus != 's') ) {
  cout << "Error, please enter either m or s!" << '\n'; // error message
  cin.clear(); // clear the error flag
  cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n'); // ignore all invalid previous input
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way could be to change the `fillingStatus` to `string` and get only the first character of that string and see if it fails or not.

Alternatively, there used to be a method for getting a character input, `getche()` I think (it has been many years since I worked in C++ so don't exactly recall)...you maybe able to use that too.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you are only reading the input one character at a time, your are essentially unable to tell that the user has input more and it is being held until you read more from the input stream.

Using a `string` to read a line of data at a time and having the program react to that string as a whole will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::string filingStatus ;
while(!(cin >> filingStatus ) || ( filingStatus  != "m" && filingStatus  != "f") )
{
    cin.clear();
    std::cout << "Error, please enter either m or s!" << '\n';
};
```